# How to improve the performance of this query in oracle 12c using join?

Tags: sql, oracle12c

I have the following query:

```
   SELECT PERIODO, PERIODO_ID,
   DWH_DIM_IES.IES_CARACTER AS CARACTER,  COUNT(CASE WHEN estado_PERIODO=1 THEN estado_PERIODO ELSE NULL END) as desertores,
   COUNT(*) as matriculados
   FROM DWH_H_D_PERIODO_SISTEMA
   JOIN DWH_DIM_IES ON DWH_H_D_PERIODO_SISTEMA.IES_ID = DWH_DIM_IES.IES_ID 
   GROUP by PERIODO,PERIODO_ID,DWH_DIM_IES.IES_CARACTER
   ORDER BY DWH_DIM_IES.IES_CARACTER,PERIODO
```

The tables are materialized views and I do not use cubes. The table `DWH_H_D_PERIODO_SISTEMA` has 31.346.470 rows and the table `DWH_DIM_IES` has 328 rows. This query takes 15 seconds. If add indexes to tables then the query time increases to 29 seconds. How I can improve time?

I created the indexes like this:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX INDEX_IES_ID ON DWH_DIM_IES (IES_ID);
CREATE INDEX DWH_H_D_PER_IES_ID ON DWH_H_D_PERIODO_SISTEMA (IES_ID ASC);
```

Comment: Did you create the right index for your query?  You probably need to show the commands you used, and perhaps the output of `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` (or the Oracle equivalent) on your query.

Comment: This is the command:

     CREATE UNIQUE INDEX INDEX_IES_ID ON DWH_DIM_IES (IES_ID);
     CREATE INDEX DWH_H_D_PER_IES_ID ON      DWH_H_D_PERIODO_SISTEMA (IES_ID ASC) 

And this is the ORACLE EXPLAIN ANALYZE  here [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/kg1mr44kyilkgv7/EXPLAIN%20ANALYZE.html?dl=0)

Comment: It's best to use the [edit] link to add the information to your question.  I've done that for you for the indexes, but your link appears to go to an empty page, so you'll need to add the EXPLAIN result yourself.  HTH.  (P.S. sorry I don't have an answer - I know nothing about Oracle databases, just trying to improve your question to attract better answers).